# Can't uninstall or upgrade git

Tags: linux, git, updates, opensuse, zypper

I'm on openSUSE ver 12.2. My git seems to be installed in `/usr/lib`.

```
rnx@linux-sh2d2:~> git --version
git version 1.7.10.4
rnx@linux-sh2d2:~> which git
/usr/bin/git
rnx@linux-sh2d2:~> cd /usr/bin/
rnx@linux-sh2d2:/usr/bin> ls -l git
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Jan 10 01:23 git -> ../lib/git/git-add
```

I have already done a `zypper remove`. Now when I say `zipper remove git` it shows:

```
Loading repository data...
Warning: Repository 'openSUSE-12.2-Update' appears to outdated. Consider using a different mirror or server.
Reading installed packages...
Package 'git' is not installed.
'git' not found in package names. Trying capabilities.
No provider of 'git' is installed.
Resolving package dependencies...
Nothing to do.
```

but with `which git` or `git --version` I get the same result as noted earlier (above).
My intention is to update git. I tried cloning:

```
git clone https://github.com/git/git
```

It says:

```
fatal: destination path 'git' already exists and is not an empty directory
```

I know it's not empty.

I did a `zypper search git`. The result is:

```
S | Name                       | Summary                            | Type      
--+----------------------------+------------------------------------+-----------
  | cgit                       | A web frontend for git repositor-> | package   
  | cgit                       | A web frontend for git repositor-> | srcpackage
  | clucene-git                | Open Source C++ Search Engine      | srcpackage
  | clucene-git-debugsource    | Debug sources for package clucen-> | package   
  | git                        | Fast, scalable, distributed revi-> | package   
  | git                        | Fast, scalable, distributed revi-> | srcpackage
  | git-arch                   | Git tools for importing Arch rep-> | package   
i | git-core                   | Core git tools                     | package   
i | git-cvs                    | Git tools for importing CVS repo-> | package   
  | git-daemon                 | Simple Server for Git Repositories | package   
i | git-email                  | Git tools for sending email        | package   
i | git-gui                    | Grapical tool for common git ope-> | package   
  | git-remote-helpers         | Python package for remote helper-> | package   
i | git-svn                    | Git tools for importing Subversi-> | package   
i | git-web                    | Git Web Interface                  | package   
  | gitg                       | Git repository viewer              | package   
  | gitg-lang                  | Languages for package gitg         | package   
i | gitk                       | Git revision tree visualiser       | package   
  | glade-catalog-gitg         | Git repository viewer -- Catalog-> | package   
  | hg-git                     | Mercurial Plugin for Communicati-> | package   
  | libgit2-0                  | C git library                      | package   
  | libgit2-devel              | C git library                      | package   
  | libgitg-1_0-0              | Git repository viewer -- Library   | package   
  | libgitg-devel              | Git repository viewer -- Develop-> | package   
  | perl-Algorithm-CheckDigits | Perl extension to generate and t-> | package   
  | perl-Config-GitLike        | Git-compatible config file parsing | package   
  | python-GitPython           | Python Git Library                 | package   
  | python-git-review          | Tool to submit code to Gerrit      | package   
  | python-git-review          | Tool to submit code to Gerrit      | srcpackage
  | python-gitdb               | Git Object Database                | package   
  | qgit                       | Graphical Git Repository Viewer    | package   
  | stgit                      | Stacked GIT - Source Code Manage-> | package   
  | vim-plugin-gitdiff         | Show git diff in a split window    | package
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How did you install git? Have you tried `zypper search git` to see what's the full package name?

Comment: @choroba edited my question to include what you asked. Thanks. Also I guess the git was installed from the opensuse dvd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see, `git-core` is installed, which is the minimal package of git tools. Try `zypper remove git-core`.

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly- problem solved! Updated to 1.9.0.